# My C++ Merge Sort code isn't working. What am i missing here?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, debugging, mergesort

*In my code , `lb` refers to lower bound and `ub` refers to upper bound.I'm using the `mergeSort function` to recursively split the array into smaller pieces and the `merge function` to merge in their sorted order.*

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void merge(int input[], int lb, int ub, int size)
{
    int i = lb;
    int k = 0;
    int mid = (lb + ub) / 2;
    int j = mid + 1;

    int *arr = new int[size];

    while (i <= mid && j <= ub)
    {
        if (input[i] <= input[j])
            arr[k++] = input[i++];
        else
            arr[k++] = input[i++];
    }
    while (i <= mid)
        arr[k++] = input[i++];
    while (j <= ub)
        arr[k++] = input[j++];

    for (k = 0; k < size; k++)
        input[k] = arr[k];
}
void mergeSort(int input[], int size)
{
    int lb = 0;
    int ub = size - 1;
    int mid;
    if (size == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    else if (lb < ub)
    {
        mid = (lb + ub) / 2;
        mergeSort(input, mid - lb + 1);
        mergeSort(input + mid + 1, ub - mid);
        merge(input, lb, ub, size);
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int input[1000], length;
    cin >> length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        cin >> input[i];
    mergeSort(input, length);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        cout << input[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: In the `else` branch of the first `while` loop in `merge`, you have used `i` instead of `j`. (But please consider reorganizing your code. You have many redundant variables which are often just inclusive upper bounds that complement other data. Make them exclusive, as is customary in C++, and you'll see that you need only `mid` and `size`.)

Comment: the second half of your `mergeSort` function isn't working properly. I copied your code and added some debugging output and when it goes to sort the second half of the array, it fails to actually do anything.

Comment: You also forgot to `delete[]` all the `new`ed `arr`s.

Comment: thanks everyone.changing i++ to j++ in the `first else` solved it. Passed all test cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used i istead of j in the first while loop in merge function. The correct code is the following

```
while (i <= mid && j <= ub) { 
        if (input[i] <= input[j]) 
           arr[k++] = input[i++]; 
       else 
           arr[k++] = input[j++];     
}
```